# How to solve for the probability of this problem?

Tags: probability, problem-solving

Suppose Boyet, a basketball player, has an 85% chance of making free throw. Over the whole game, he attempts 5 free throws. What is the probability that he will miss at least one of them?

So I'm literally having a hard time understanding what how to get the independent probability on this problem. How would I know what's the two events that intersected in this situation? How can I use the independent formula in this one?

Comment: think of probability that the player makes all $5$ of them and if you can find it, can you find what is asked?

Comment: It sounds like the problem assumes that each free throw is considered independent from one another.

Comment: Let $A_1$ be the event that he is successful at making his first free throw.  Let $A_2$ be the event that he is successful at making the second free throw, etc... on up to $A_5$ for the fifth.  You are asked for $\Pr(A_1^c\cup A_2^c\cup \dots \cup A_5^c)$ which you should recognize is $\Pr((A_1\cap A_2\cap \dots \cap A_5)^c)$ or $1 - \Pr(A_1\cap A_2\cap \dots \cap A_5)$.  Now... it is common for an introductory problem like this to assume that $A_1,A_2,\dots$ are independent (*even if in reality they might not be, having missed the first two might have shaken his nerves making him worse*)

Comment: Hint: The prob. to miss at least of them is 1 minus the prob. to miss none of them.

Comment: Thanks for your answerss!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Total probability is equal to the chance the desired situation happens plus the chance that it does not happen.

`P(missing no shots) + P(missing 1 or more shots) = 1`

`P(missing 1 or more shots) = 1 - P(missing no shots)`

Each free throw is independent of each other with the same probability

`P(missing no shots) = P(making one shot)^(attempted shots)`

As the probability of making one shot is given as 85% and the number of attempted shots is given as 5, we can evaluate the this equation.

`P(missing no shots) = (0.85)^5`

`P(missing 1 or more shots) = 1-0.4437053125`

`P(missing 1 or more shots) = 0.5562946875 = 55.62946875%`

Comment: Thank you so muchhh!!!